# Node.js encoding not UTF-8

Tags: arrays, node.js, encoding

I read html page encoded win1251. But I cant render it, because it shows me bad encoded symbols. with utf8 this code works fine. How can I read and show not utf8? Thanks

```
var charset = require('charset');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var router = express.Router();


// accept POST request on the homepage
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

  request(req.body.url, function (error, response, body) {

    var result = [];
    if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log(error);

    } else {
        console.log(charset(response.headers, body));
        var enc = charset(response.headers, body);
        if (enc != 'utf-8') {

            body = iconv.decode(body, 'win1251');
            console.log(body);
        }
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        //get title
        result.push("Title-> " + $("title").text());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `encoding: null` in your `request()` options, `body` will be a `Buffer` instead of a UTF-8 string. This will allow you to correctly convert the encoding to UTF-8.

Example:

```
request({url: req.body.url, encoding: null}, function (error, response, body) {
```

If the encoding of the body ends up being UTF-8, you can simply just do:

```
body = body.toString('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets this problem too. I did instead of (which is good too)

```
body = body.toString('utf8');
```

My code

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
.......................

body = iconv.decode(body, 'win1251');
```